# Is it possible to perform munmap based on information in /proc/self/maps?

Tags: c, linux

I need to be able to unmap files that were opened through some libraries I'm linking with. The reason for needing to do this is that the mappings made by these libraries hold references to modules that may need to be reloaded while the program is executing (potentially long running executions). The problem is the modules cannot be unloaded while my process is holding a reference.

I've written C code to parse the information in `proc/self/maps` in an effort to read the address range of the mappings and calculate its length. I've calculated the length by subtracting the starting address from the ending address then I pass the starting address and the calculated length as the respective parameters to `munmap`. The problem is that `munmap` fails with EINVAL (Invalid Argument).

I've checked the size of the page my machine uses with `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` and it returned 4096, which is the value of my calculated length. The GNU manual says that `munmap` can fail with EINVAL if:

> The memory range given was outside the user mmap range or wasn’t page
>   aligned.

Am I missing anything or is this at all not possible? My last resort would be to carefully comb through the system calls made and examine each `mmap` via `strace`, but I'd like for this to be a last resort, thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but unmapping a file from your code without informing the code which uses it sound like recipe for disaster. If the library can be unloaded, it should provide some means to release the files in a controlled way.

Comment: @Olaf The code that uses it does not provide a means to unmap since any API calls perform a re-initialization if necessary. Mappings only occur after any API calls. I'll admit I'm not currently sure if things will work at all, but that's not my question; just some background. I'd just like to know if I'm using the information in `/proc/self/maps` correctly with `munmap`, and if not, where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Have you checked that you are really passing `munmap` the arguments you think you are?  I would wonder if there is a bug in your arithmetic in computing the address and/or size.

Comment: I think you need to provide a more concrete explanation of the first paragraph. A reference to what exactly? This does seem like an XY problem.

Comment: @NateEldredge, yes, that was exactly what was off, I was not really passing `munmap` the arguments I think I was. See my answer below, your comment prompted me to have a closer look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I had a closer look at my code; there was something I was misunderstanding when it came to passing the start address of the mapping to `munmap`. I had initially read the start address into an unsigned long long and for some reason, I was converting this value into a hex string instead of just casting to a void pointer when calling `munmap`. In essence:

```
/* Values assigned here are really read from /proc/self/maps */
unsigned long long vm_start = 140013986873344;
unsigned long long vm_end   = 140013986877440;

unsigned long long length = vm_end - vm_start;
munmap((void *)vm_start, length);
```

Answer (score 3):

The method you have chosen will *not* work, but, not necessarily for the reason(s) you think. However, there is a way, so read on ...

> I need to be able to unmap files that were opened through some libraries I'm **linking** with.

Once you've let the ELF loader (e.g. `ld.linux.so`) load the libraries for you, you've lost control.

You can *not* just unmap the area [*regardless* of method]. The loader has already done relocations and symbol linkages for these libraries. The unmap removes the area, but now everything breaks because the various pointers set up by the linker now point to empty space. The loader will have no knowledge of what you've done.

Then, how would you remap the new version of the library [and where in memory]? Even remapping it to the same address is no guarantee because you can't adjust the things that the loader has already done.

> The reason for needing to do this is that the mappings made by these libraries hold references to **modules** that may need to be reloaded while the program is executing (potentially long running executions).

Most programs that need to update to new versions of libraries simply reexec themselves. If you need to preserve the data, you can work out a dump/restore mechanism.

However, if you truly want to unload/load a newer library version, you can do this using *dynamic* linking.

Instead of using `ld` to *link* with (e.g.) `libA`, leave if off the `ld` command line and have the program do its own loading of `libA`.

You use `dlopen/dlsym/dlclose` to open/load the library under your control.

You'll have to keep track of the symbol tables, but changing to the new version is easy. When you want the new version, simply do `dlclose` and then a `dlopen`. You'll have to redo the `dlsym` calls to get the updated addresses, but all this is fairly easy and standard

> The problem is the modules cannot be unloaded while my process is holding a reference.

The reason is that ELF loader did this. With `dlopen` et. al., you don't have the same problem.