# Are functions marked with __attribute__(constructor) run again when a shared library is reloaded?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, shared-libraries

Assume that no other executable linked against a shared library `libshlib` has already been loaded. And assume `libshlib` contains one function marked with `__attribute__(constructor)` and one function marked with `__attribute__(destructor)`. When executable that is linked against `libshlib` is started, `libshlib` will be loaded and  the corresponding function marked with `__attribute(constructor)` is run *exactly* once. But what happens if the shared library can be reloaded e.g. via a user defined signal such as `SIGUSR1`? From my testing it seems that the `__attribute__(constructor)` is not run again. Is that correct or is there a standard saying otherwise?

Comment: How do you reload the shared library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have a program that was *linked* via (e.g.):

```
cc -o mypgm mypgm.o -lshlib
```

Upon execution, once the ELF interpreter has loaded `libshlib.so` and executed the constructor(s), the library is never loaded again. *Side note:* To find your interpreter do: `readelf -a mypgm | grep interpreter:`

If the program receives a signal (e.g. `SIGUSR1`), the signal is either caught by a signal handler (assuming `signal` or `sigaction` has been called to set one up), or the default action is taken (which is [IIRC] program termination for `SIGUSR1`). This does *not* cause the library to be reloaded.

There is *no* other action that can cause the library to be reloaded either. Only the destructor(s) will be called upon program exit (e.g. `main` returns or `exit` is called).

Even *manually* calling the destructors has no effect because the constructors and destructors are independent. (e.g. The constructor could do `able = malloc(...)` and the destructor could do `free(able)`. But, the destructor could do `free(baker)` instead.). Calling a destructor does not "reset" a constructor.

To get the "reload" effect, the library would need to be *dynamically* loaded/unloaded via `dlopen/dlsym/dlclose`.  That is, the link command would be:

```
cc -o mypgm mypgm.o
```

Then, `mypgm` would [at some point] call `dlopen("libshlib.so")` (and the constructor(s) would be called). When [and *if*] `mypgm` calls `dlclose`, `libshlib.so` will be unloaded (and destructor(s) called).

If `mypgm` then called `dlopen("libshlib.so")` a *second* time, the contructors *would* be called [again].

---

**UPDATE:**

> Note that calling `dlclose` does not *necessarily* unload the library or call destructors.

I just checked the code [in `glibc`]. The library has a refcount. The library *will* be unloaded if the refcount is 1 upon entry to `dlclose`, which should be the case for `libshlib.so` above with `dlopen` [as nobody else bumps it up].

In other words, to force the "desired" behavior nothing else should refer to `libshlib` via an `-lshlib`. Not the program or any other `.so`. This lays the groundwork.

Note that if `libshlib.so` wanted `glibc`, but so did the program, unloading `libshlib` will bump down the `glibc` refcount, but `glibc` will remain because its refcount is [still] >0.

> There are conditions where the library can't be unloaded (in fact, these conditions are much more common then conditions when the library can be unloaded).

Again, this is dependent upon the refcount and [possibly] some state. When the library is loaded from a "static" linkage (vs. `dlopen`), the refcount gets an extra increment, so it won't get yanked.

The code also handles the case where a constructor calls `dlopen` on its *own* library.

For a given `libA`, if it needs `libB`, B's refcount gets upped/downed by A's load/unload.

> If the library is not unloaded, then it's not well defined whether destructors will run, and whether the subsequent dlopen will run constructors again

The whole point of using `dlopen` this way for `libshlib` is to *guarantee* the loading at `dlopen` and unloading at `dlclose` [along with constructor/destructor action]. This *will* be true if there is no static reference to it or cyclic dependency, which was the starting criteria.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> The part about "as nobody else bumps it up" is way too simplistic.

Don't confuse prose with substance.

As mentioned above: *This **will** be true if there is no static reference to it or cyclic dependency*.

This means that *only* the executable/object that does the `dlopen/dlclose` for `shlib` refers to a symbol in `shlib`.

And, this is *only* via `dlsym`. Otherwise, it's a static reference (i.e. in the object's symbol table as UNDEF)].

And, *no* shared library that `shlib` drags in refers to a symbol defined in `shlib` [the cyclic dependency].

> Look at all the places where DF_1_NODELETE is set during symbol resolution.

Yes, I *did* look.

`DF_1_NODELETE` is set in *only* the following places. None of them apply to this situation [or most `dlopen` scenarios].

1. If the *flags* argument to `dlopen` has `RTLD_NODELETE`, which we can avoid.
2. If profiling is enabled, the *profile* map [*not* related to our `dlopen`] gets `DF_1_NODELETE` set
3. If a symbol has a bind type (e.g. `LOCAL`, `GLOBAL`, `WEAK`, etc.) that is type 10 (`STB_GNU_UNIQUE`)
4. A symbol is referenced by a non-dynamic object as an UNDEF [in its symbol table] that can't be removed [because the referent object has DF_1_NODELETE set]. This does not apply because of the pre-conditions above.
5. There was `malloc` failure when adding a dependency [from a _different object]. This code doesn't even execute for the case herein.

And, OP's usage aside, there are legitimate reasons for `dlopen/dlclose` to work as I've set up/described.

See my answer here: [Is it possible to perform munmap based on information in /proc/self/maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732412/is-it-possible-to-perform-munmap-based-on-information-in-proc-self-maps/36733911#36733911)

There, OP needed to have a *nonstop* program that could run for months/years (e.g. a hi-reliabilty, mission-critical application). If an updated version of one of its shared libraries was installed [via a package manager, etc.], the program had to dynamically, on-the-fly, *without* a re-exec, be able to load the newer version.

Comment: Note that calling `dlclose` does not *necessarily* unload the library or call destructors. There are conditions where the library can't be unloaded (in fact, these conditions are much more common then conditions when the library *can* be unloaded). If the library is not unloaded, then it's not well defined whether destructors will run, and whether the subsequent `dlopen` will run constructors again.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I've done a little research and updated my answer to address your concerns [hopefully :-)].

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't clear about one thing: I've implemented a signal handler that reloads the shlib on `SIGUSR1`.

Comment: @CraigEstey The part about "as nobody else bumps it up" is way too simplistic. Look at all the places where `DF_1_NODELETE` is set during symbol resolution.

Comment: @lord.garbage If by "signal handler that realoads" you mean that your symbol handler `dlclose`es and `dlopen`s the library, note that your program  is using undefined behavior (and will explode in your face at most inopportune time): you can't call `dlclose`, `dlopen`, or any other non-async-signal safe function from a signal handler.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and post your build commands and the signaling and handling code, and how you're loading/unloading the lib. I agree that this should _not_ be done from a signal handler. But, with a bit of restructuring, it doesn't need to be (See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38314131/5382650). Also, a bit more of the intent/context. Remember, I'm on your side in trying to get this to work

Comment: @EmployedRussian Re. `DF_1_NODELETE`: It doesn't apply here. I've updated my answer to explain why.

Comment: "doesn't apply" -- why doesn't `STB_GNU_UNIQUE` case apply here? Anyway, I am not going to argue anymore, but the fact remains: `dlopen/dlsym/dlclose` does not *guarantee* that the library will be unloaded.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I'm going to stop, too. The GNU doesn't apply because we specifically exclude it from our `shlib` [and it's arch dependent and doesn't apply to x86 AFAICT]. Also, anything else that would cause failure. We're getting the guarantee because we construct the lib in such a way that it will succeed [by avoiding anything that would cause a failure]. If we need 10 extra linker options to accomplish this, then that's what we'd do.